# Example of centralizer of a dual Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, definition, banach-spaces, dual-spaces

[Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centralizer_and_normalizer) states the following definition of a centralizer of a Banach space.

> Let $(X,\|\cdot\|)$ be a Banach space over a field $\mathbb{K}$ and let Ext$(X)$ be the set of extreme points of the closed unit ball of the continuous dual space $X^*.$
> A continuous linear operator $T:X\to X$ is said to be a **multiplier** if every point in Ext$(X)$ is an eigenvector for the adjoint operator $T^*:X\to X,$ that is, there exists a function $a_T:Ext(X) \to \mathbb{K}$ such that
> $$p \circ T = a_T(p)p$$ for all $p\in Ext(X).$
> Given two multipliers $S$ and $T$ on $X,$ $S$ is said to be an **adjoint** for $T$ if
> $$a_s = a_T.$$ (I only consider real case)
> The **centralizer** of $X,$ denoted $Z(X),$ is the set of all multipliers on $X$ for which an adjoint exists.

**Question:** Suppose that $X = \mathbb{R}$ with Euclidean norm $\|\cdot\|_2.$ What are some examples of centralizer of $\mathbb{R}?$
I have trouble giving example for centralizer. Any hint would be appreciated.

EDITED: Based on comment given by Nate,it seems that $X=\mathbb{R}$ is quite 'trivial'. I would like to ask what about $X=\mathbb{R}^2$ with $\|\cdot\|_1$, that is, $\|(x,y)\|_1=|x|+|y|$?

Comment: Over the field $\mathbb{K} = \mathbb{R}$, every multiplier is trivially its own adjoint, so the centralizer is the set of all multipliers.  This is confirmed [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=al95RjHrDUgC&lpg=PA20&ots=gV7hy8sZMU&dq=centralizer%20banach%20space&pg=PA18#v=onepage&q=centralizer%20banach%20space&f=false).  For $X = \mathbb{R}$ you should be able to show that every operator is a multiplier.

Comment: I think you'll find that in any real Hilbert space, the only multipliers are constant multiples of the identity.  This should follow from the fact that every point of the unit sphere is an extreme point of the unit ball.

Comment: @Nate What about my edited question?